# hiding passwords in Octopus deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm deploying a web app into DEV, TEST and PROD environments. One of the variables on the Octopus server holds the appPool user and password.

It makes sense for developers to edit this value within DEV, but they should not be able to see the values for TEST or PROD etc.

It looks like the permissions defined within Octopus allow "variables - view" to be scoped to Project, but not environment...

Is there a better way around this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a supported feature in recent versions of Octopus - please see this blog post for details:

http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/environment-specific-variable-permission

Using this, you can set up a rule like "Developers cannot view or edit variables in the *Production* environment".

Comment: Just updated to the latest version. This fits our requirements. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you could encrypt a version of your password and use that in the octopus variable and then in you deploy.ps1 script as you create the app pool dencrypt it.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of setup, but its the only option short of manually setting up IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can give variables the same name and scope to each to its respective Environment to get exactly what you want. http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Variables

Taking a step back, you could also revisit Windows Authentication\NTLM integrated security for ACLs, NTFS permissions, database access and such. If this is an IIS Application Pool, for example, you can look into granting the Windows Domain machine account access, if it is using Network Service. See the bottom of this page https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities